# Does $\operatorname{Int} ( A \cup ( X \setminus \overline{A}) ) = \operatorname{Int} ( A ) \cup \operatorname{Int} ( X \setminus \overline{A})$?

Tags: general-topology

I was working on a problem and I got stuck at this point:

> Let $X$ be a topological space, and let $A \subseteq X$. Then does $\operatorname{Int} ( A \cup ( X \setminus \overline{A}) ) = \operatorname{Int} ( A ) \cup \operatorname{Int} ( X \setminus \overline{A})$?

Answer (score 0):

Not in general. If $A$ is any nonempty closed set with empy interior, then $\overline{A}=A$ has no interior, so $\text{int}\, B=X\neq \text{int}\,A+\,\text{int}\,{X\setminus \overline{A}}=\text{int}\,X\setminus\overline{A}=X\setminus{A}$.